# How to enable `request` on Rails module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote a little helper for my app in `app/helpers/currency_helper.rb`, but one method in it depends on `request`. It seem `request` is not available from within the Module. Here's my code:

```
module CurrencyHelper

    def define_currency
        ...
        location = request.location
        ... 
    end

end
```

And I have included the above module in my Model and ApplicationController:

```
include CurrencyHelper
```

All other methods within the module works fine as expected but whenever I execute `define_currency` I get the error: `undefined local variable or method 'request' for #<Voice:0x007ff02d43bc30>`

How can I make `request` available from my module? Alternatively, where else can I define this method that will be available both at Controller and Model level?

PS: Note that I've tried adding the method within `ApplicationController` which did work for `Controllers` but not on `Models`

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to achieve is for the Model to be formatted based on the request location (pseudo-code, please note I'm using the [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com) gem):

```
class Model
  ...
  def localize
    ...
    if request.location == "GB"
      self.as_json(method: method_available_for_both_model_and_controller)
    else
      self.as_son(method: another_method)
    end
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Due to the MVC separation, your models (business logic) would normally never deal with the request:  that is the controller's job.  You could change it so that it takes the request as a parameter.  Alternatively,  Is it an option to use `I18n.locale` instead of `request.location`?  `I18n.locale` is available everywhere and is updated to whatever the current user's locale is with every request.

Comment: Unfortunately `I18n.locale` wouldn't do. What do you suggest in order to have this module available to both a Model and a Controller?

Answer (score 1):

Models should not know anything about `request`, because their lifespans differ - models can be accessed after request has completed or even if there's no request at all.

So pass it each time from controller, or set a thread-local variable in an around-filter or `request_store` gem, but doing so you should be completely sure you know what goes when.

Comment: The problem is that i can't pass parameter to Modules... Any suggestions other than create a gem?

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK To pass something you can either pass it directly, or put somewhere the other side can get it. For example directly - `your_model.localize(request.location)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried, although I was getting an error: `Wrong number of arguments provided (1 of 0)` (not word by word). After doing some reading, I have the impression the a module's method - like my CurrencyHelper - cannot have arguments. Is that correct?